# Picom: Failed to trigger fence

Tags: xorg, i3-window-manager

I would like to get transparent terminals in i3 under Ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia drivers 435.21, but I can't get it to work.
When I execute `picom`, I get the following output:

```
[ 11.11.2020 20:51:24.270 x_fence_sync ERROR ] Failed to trigger the fence (X error 136 XSyncBadFence request 134 minor 15 serial 2033)
[ 11.11.2020 20:51:24.270 paint_all ERROR ] x_fence_sync failed, xrender-sync-fence will be disabled from now on.
```

When I run `picom -f`, the windows successfully fade in, so transparency itself is working, but it seems that my terminals can't access it.

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an issue with my terminal configuration. `picom` works just fine for me, despite the error messages.

Answer (score 9):

I'm running nvidia driver at the moment as well. I just started picom with `--xrender-sync-fence` option and that error message has gone away. My full command is

`picom --experimental-backends --backend glx --xrender-sync-fence`
picom help shows

```
--xrender-sync-fence
  Additionally use X Sync fence to sync clients' draw calls. Needed
  on nvidia-drivers with GLX backend for some users.
``
```